# Linq dynamic orderby not working

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know how to make a dynamic Linq query.

This is working:

```
var query = from article in context.DP_ARTICLES
            orderby article.ART_NUM descending
            select new ArticleItem() { Article = article };
```

But this is not working:

```
var query = from article in context.DP_ARTICLES
            orderby("ART_NUM DESC")
            select new ArticleItem() { Article = article };
```

EDIT:

The goal is to order a listview columns, so in my method i get the sql column name as string parameter(eg ART_NUM). So the best is to use it directly in my query instead of make a switch ...

Comment: https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Agreed, that probably does not compile.  You can't use string literals to identify the field.

Comment: Why do you expect that this should work ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Change the order by field depending on some other condition?

Comment: `orderby` isn't a function. You typed the equivalent of `orderby "ART_NUM DESC"`. You simply passed a static string to the operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic methods only work when using the method syntax of the calls, it will not work when using the query syntax.

```
var query = context.DP_ARTICLES
    .OrderBy("ART_NUM DESC")
    .Select(a => new ArticleItem { Article = a });
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? I ran a successful example using query syntax.

Comment: If you were to just pass in a string in the query syntax, nothing would actually happen as you're sorting using a constant.  it's effectively the same as if you called it as `.OrderBy(e => "ART_NUM DESC")` or even `.OrderBy(e => 1)`.

Comment: Doh, of course. I was so shocked it even accepted the syntax I didn't pay attention to the fact that it didn't actually sort correctly.

Comment: I tried this example and it is working

Answer (score 1):

if your query is based on a predicate then you could do the following:

```
var query = context.DP_ARTICLES; 

if(predicate) 
   query=  query.OrderBy(article => article.ART_NUM).AsQueryable();
else if(predicate2) 
   query = //Second Order by clause
.... //More sort options
else 
   //Default action if needed

var results = query.select(article => new ArticleItem
                                      { 
                                          Article = article
                                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Note, first OrderBy will return OrderedEnumerable<T>, and the extension OrderBy wants Queryable<T>.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen updated to return queryable

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

`orderby("ART_NUM DESC")`

to

`orderby article.ART_NUM descending`

as orderby doesn't accept string literals.

Comment: That's really interesting, I didn't actually try it myself. Did you try it with the exact (or very similar) syntax that OP used?

Comment: OK, I'm a dolt. I was just surprised it accepted the syntax, but it doesn't actually perform the sort correctly.

Comment: Talking about Linq.Dynamic.OrderBy here, not standard Linq.OrderBy which does accept a string